# How to get the value as an array of strings from powershell hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, key-value

I have an array of hash table containing key value pairs, like below:

```
$myTest = @{};
$test1 = @{
    Name = "Food1"
    Value = "Sandwich"
    }
    $test2 = @{
    Name = "Food2"
    Value = "Salad"
    }
$myTest["Food1"] = $test1;
$myTest["Food2"] = $test2
```

On running the command
`$myUpdatedTest = $myTest.Values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`

gives the value in
`$myUpdatedTest` --> `[{"Value":"Sandwich","Name":"Food1"},{"Value":"Salad","Name":"Food2"}]`

And if I have only `$test1` added to the `$myTest` then the value comes in as `{"Value":"Sandwich","Name":"Food1"}`
But in the later case I want the value to be inside `[]` --> `[{"Value":"Sandwich","Name":"Food1"}]` is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Avoid piping the input: `$myUpdatedTest = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $myTest.Values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with this is how you are sending the object to the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet.

I managed to get this working by changing

```
$myUpdatedTest = $myTest.Values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

to

```
$myUpdatedTest = ConvertTo-Json -Compress -InputObject $myTest.Values
```

This then evaluates the whole `$myTest.Values` object as opposed to each value one by one. I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Kinda clunky, but this works:

```
$myTest = @{};
$test1 = @{
Name = "Food1"
Value = "Sandwich"
}
$test2 = @{
Name = "Food2"
Value = "Salad"
}
$myTest["Food1"] = $test1;
$myTest["Food2"] = $test2

if($myTest){

    if($myTest.Count -eq 1){

        $myUpdatedTest = "[$($myTest.Values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)]"
    }else{

        $myUpdatedTest = $myTest.Values | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    }
}

$myUpdatedTest
```

Comment: Thanks @nimizen, I wanted to avoid the if condition (should've mentioned in the question)